# Predicting classes with a lot of data skewed towards one class

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, classification, prediction

I have a question on how to deal with some interesting data.

I currently have some data (The counts are real, but the situation is fake) where we predict the number of t-shirts that people will purchase online today.  We know quite a bit about everyone for our feature attributes and these change from day to day.  We also know how many t-shirts the everyone purchased the previous days.

What I want is to have an algorithm that is able to churn out a continuous variable that is a ranking or “score” of the number of t-shirts the person is going to purchase the today.  My end goal is that if I can get this score attached to each person, I can sort them according to the score and use them in a specific UI.  Currently I’ve been using random forest regression with sci-kit where my target classes are yesterday’s count of t-shirt purchases by each person.  This has worked out pretty well except that my data is mildly difficult in that there are a lot of people that purchase 0 t-shirts.  This is a problem due to my random forest giving me a lot of predicted classes of 0 and I cannot sort them effectively.  I get why this is happening, but I’m not sure the best way to get around it.

What I want is a non-zero score (even if it’s a very small number close to 0) that tells me more about the features and the predicted class.  I feel that some of my features must be able to tell me something and give me a better prediction than 0.

I think that the inherent problem is using random forest regressor as the algorithm.  Each tree is getting a vote; however, there are so many zeros that there are many forests where all trees are voting for 0.  I would like another algorithm to try, but i don’t know which one would work best.  Currently I’m training on the whole dataset and using the out-of-bag estimate that scikit provides.

Here are the counts (using python’s Counter([target classes]) of the data classes.  This is setup as such: {predicted_class_value: counts_of_that_value_in_the_target_class_list}
{0: 3560426, 1: 121256, 2: 10582, 3: 1029, 4: 412, 5: 88, 6: 66, 7: 35, 8: 21, 9: 17, 10: 17, 11: 10, 12: 2, 13: 2, 15: 2, 21: 2, 17: 1, 18: 1, 52: 1, 25: 1}

I have tried some things to manipulate the training data, but I’m really guessing at things to do.

One thing I tried was scaling the number of zeros in the training set to a linearly scaled amount based on the other data.  So instead of passing the algorithm 3.5 million 0-class rows, I scaled it down to 250,000.  So my training set looked like: {0: 250,000, 1: 121256, 2: 10582, 3: 1029, … }.  This has a drastic effect on the amount of 0’s coming back from the algorithm.  I’ve gone from the algo guessing 99% of the data as 0 to about only 50%.  However, I don’t know if this is a valid thing to do or if it even makes sense.

Other things I’ve tried include increasing the forest size - however that doesn’t have too much of an effect, telling the random forest to only use sqrt features for each of the tree - which has had a pretty good effect, and using the out-of-bag estimate - which also has seem to have good results.

To summarize, I have a set of data where there is a disproportionate amount of data toward one class.  I would like to have some way to produce a continuous value that is a “score” for each value in the predicted dataset so I may sort them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an unbalanced class problem. One thing you could do is over/undersampling. Undersampling means that you randomely delete instances from the majority class. Over sampling means that you sample with replacement instances from the minority class. Or you could use a combination of both. One thing you could try is SMOTE[1] which is an oversampling algorithm but instead of just sampling exsisting instances from the minority class, it creates synthetic instances which will avoid overfitting and in theory will be better at generalizing.

[1] Chawla, Nitesh V., et al. "SMOTE: synthetic minority over-sampling technique." Journal of artificial intelligence research (2002): 321-357.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  This is really helpful and it has led me to some great documentation.